# ListFragment (listview) переходы

Tags: android, java

Хочу поставить в каждую строку свой фрагмент, но не могу понять как, т.к новичок. Прошу помощи.

```
     public class MainListStudioMax extends ListFragment {      
// Array of strings storing country names
         String[] countries = new String[] {        
"India",        
"Pakistan",         
"SrLanka",      
"China",        
"Bangladesh",
"Nepal",        
"Afghanistan",      
"NorthKorea",       
"South Korea",      
"Japan" };

         // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable/
         int[] flags = new int[]{       R.drawable.india,
            R.drawable.pakistan,
            R.drawable.srilanka,
            R.drawable.china,
            R.drawable.bangladesh,
            R.drawable.nepal,
            R.drawable.afghanistan,
            R.drawable.nkorea,
            R.drawable.skorea,
            R.drawable.japan    
         };

         // Array of strings to store currencies
         String[] currency = new String[]{
            "Indian Rupee",
            "Pakistani Rupee",
            "Sri Lankan Rupee",
            "Renminbi",
            "Bangladeshi Taka",
            "Nepalese Rupee",
            "Afghani",
            "North Korean Won",
            "South Korean Won",
            "Japanese Yen"
         };

        @Override   public View
     onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
     ViewGroup container,Bundle
     savedInstanceState) {

            // Each row in the list stores
     country name, currency and flag
             List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new
     ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

             for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                 hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
                 hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
                 hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );

                 aList.add(hm);        
             }

             // Keys used in Hashmap
             String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

             // Ids of views in listview_layout
             int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
             // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
             SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
     aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from,
     to);

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            return super.onCreateView(inflater,
     container, savedInstanceState);            }

    @Override   
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments       
    Fragment fragment = null; 
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
    fragment = new Photo();
    break;          
    default:
    break;  }       
    if (fragment !=null)            
    switchFragment(fragment);
    }

    private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment)  {       
    // TODO: Implement this method      
    if (getActivity() ==null)

    return;     
    } }
```

LAYOUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Когда сделал так, то пишет ошибку что такого фрагмента нет и подчёркивает Photo.

*Обновление*

Использую SlidingMenu. В боковом меню настроил, что бы во фрагменте вылетал Список. В нем хочу настроить обработчик нажатий на листвиев, на каждую кнопку. Но не могу разобраться в коде чуток.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments       
    Fragment fragment = null; 
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
    fragment = new Photo();
    break;          
    default:
    break;  
}
```

Пишет ошибку, что такого фрагмента нет и подчёркивает Photo. Что я делаю не так?

*Обновление 2*

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Photo extends Fragment {

    public Photo(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: видимо и правда такого фрагмента нет. Покажите код класса Photo